# Realtime Database: Query Multiple Nodes

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my RTDB (I'm using typescript interface notation to communicate the structure):

```js
interface MyDB {
  customers: {
    [id: string]: {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
    };
  };

  projects: {
    [id: string]: {
      created: string;
      customerId: string;
      phase: string;
    };
  };
}
```

Given that I have two "tables" or document nodes, I'm not certain what the correct format for getting a project, as well as it's associated customer, should be.

I was thinking this:

```js
db.ref('projects').once(projects => {
  const customers = db.ref('customers').once(customers => {
    const project = projects[SOME_PROJECT_ID];
    const customer = customers[project.customerId];

    // Proceed to do cool stuff with our customer and project...
  });
});
```

Now, there are plenty of ways to express this. To be honest I did it this way in this example for simplicity, but I would actually not serialize the db.ref calls - I would put them in a combined observable and have them go out in parallel but that doesn't really matter because the inner code wouldn't change.

My question is -- is this how it is expected that one handle multi-document lookups that need to be joined in realtime database, or is there a "better" more "RTDB-y" way of doing it?

The issue I see here is the understanding I have is that we're selecting ALL projects and ALL customers. If I want to only get customers that have associated projects, is there a more efficient way to do that? I have seen that you might want to track project id's on each customer and do a filter there. But, I'm not sure the best way to track multiple project IDs (as a string with some kind of separater, or is there an array search function, etc?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't offer any type of SQL-like join.  If you have two locations to read, it requires two queries.  How you do those two queries is entirely up to you.  The database and its SDK is not opinionated about how you do that.  If what you have works, then go with it.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm gathering, though I was hoping for "some kind of " "somewhat opinionated guidance" in general about what the accepted best practice is. I have SQL experience so this format, i.e. shipping large queries to the client and parsing query data there, feels very inefficient. Is that really just how it's done? It strikes me as not scalable, like, could RTDB be used as an enterprise solution w/o concerns of massive data cost?

Comment: There is no opinion.  It sounds like you might want to take some time to learn about nosql data modeling techniques, if you want to improve the way your queries might work against that data.  It often involves denomalizing and duplciating data in ways that seem unnatural for SQL type databases.  This is non-trivial to learn and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting familiar with nosql design, its more the handling/processing/most efficient way to do it that I'm looking for. Do you have any recommendations for sources to learn from?